# Any Gearman tutorial?

Tags: php, gearman

I am looking for a comprehensive Gearman tutorial (preferably with the PHP API). I am trying to understand the flow of the process. I set the daemon running, create clients and workers, but how do I handle them with Gearman (like add/remove workers etc.)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For managing workers with PHP, I suggest my GearmanManager. Used by lots of people. https://github.com/brianlmoon/GearmanManager/

Comment: Thank you, but it seems to only install in RHEL and Debian :( https://github.com/brianlmoon/GearmanManager/blob/master/install/install.sh

Answer (score 15):

From a [quick Google search](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=gearman+and+php):

- http://gearman.org/?id=gearman_php_extension
- http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/Using-Gearman-from-PHP
- http://www.slideshare.net/felixdv/high-gear-php-with-gearman
- http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/240-Writing-Gearman-Workers-in-PHP.html

Answer (score 6):

[IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-gearman/) link is quite useful.