# GearMan Background Tasks

Tags: gearman

I have to use Gearman for background tasks.

someone tell me that there is a user interface for gearman, i am not able to find out any good tutorial related to gearman so through i can start learning it.

Please give good link for a beginner to learn gearman.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a good point to start is the Gearman website itself [gearman.org](http://gearman.org/getting_started) or you may look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047196/any-gearman-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the java-version.

There is an function in `ClientImpl.java`.

```
submitJob(BackendJobReturn jobReturn, 
    String functionName, 
    byte[] data, 
    GearmanJobPriority priority, 
    boolean isBackground)
```

Just let the last parameter be true, than you can run it background